# Looking at the profile of a new user

Tags: users, .profile

I created a new user (`useradd testuser`). How could I see the profile of this new user? I thought it was `cat ~testuser/.profile`, but I'm wrong.

Comment: *"but I'm wrong"*  -  so, what happened? What options and arguments did you give to the `useradd` command? FWIW, unless you have a specific requirement to use `useradd`, you might be better off using the higher-level `adduser` since this will behave more like the default.

Comment: @steeldriver If a delete `testuser` to create `testeruser` with `adduser`, is it easy to delete this user?